# Salesforce Mobile SDK Issue Login "Receiving Remote Access Authorization Error"

Tags: salesforce

I am using the salesforce mobile sdk to develop an application in native IOS. I was doing some testing logging in as a user. All was fine. Then I logged out. When I logout I call the coordinator revoke authentication method. I then tried to login as a new user who had never logged into the device and I received the following error: "Receiving Remote Access Authorization Error there was a problem in setting up your remote access." I then selected the Not me link and it logged me out. However, when I tried to login again as the user that wasn't able to login it takes me to the salesforce website for that user?!!!! It did not take me to the application but to the salesforce website? Anyone know why first the error above occurs? Does it have to do with a possible token issue? Also why would I be driven to the salesforce website when I try to login as the user again?

Note: The salesforce login is in its own webview component. I had a button to force a logout no matter where I am in the app.  When I force the logout and try to login as the person it then takes me to the application.  Very confused in terms of what is going on in this scenario.

Comment: +1 I have the exact same issue as you, the way I noticed it is that it would happen to me after I would change locations (maybe IP address?) and then try to log in again as the same user. I also wonder whether it has to do with timing out or token revocation.

Comment: Did you ever find a resolution to this?

Answer (score 0):

There is potentially a solution posted here, or at least some clues: seems to suggest a timing issue and refreshing the web view in applicationDidBecomeActive might fix it

https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/ForumsMain?id=906F00000009CBgIAM

Also more information here:

http://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000175700&language=en_US

You might also try making sure that you have a Connected App properly set up under Setup/Create/Apps, and that the key and return URL match those hardcoded in your app.